# Getting Debugger Error when trying run scheme in Emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme

I am starting SICP and have installed GNU-scheme and trying to get the scheme interpreter to output the result but I keep getting debugger errors

I tried:

```
(define pi 3.14156)

(define radius 10)

(* pi (* radius radius))
```

And got this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable radius)
  (* radius radius)
  (* pi (* radius radius))
  eval((* pi (* radius radius)))
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp)
  recursive-edit()
  byte-code("\306^P     @\307=\203!^@\310\311\312\"\210\313\311!\211^ZA@)\242\314=\203!^$
  debug(error (error "Cannot return from the debugger in an error"))
```

To run the program I do C-x, C-e

Any ideas?

Comment: but C-x,C-e is eval-last-sexp. First of all you are evaluating only one expression. Secondly, I assume it's not GNU-Scheme but emacs lisp is using.

Comment: Indeed; `C-x C-e` is *not* how you execute your scheme program.

Comment: @phils, it is in `geiser-mode`.

Comment: abo-abo: ah, ok. I guess Rahul Sharma is following some instructions which assume that geiser is installed, so your answer sounds like it's on the money.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I'm also currently working through SICP and have found it much easier to use DrRacket with and `#lang planet neil/sicp`. Obviously you know what you'll prefer, but just thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You need [geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/). And I'd recommend using `racket` for a Scheme.

Comment: Geiser requires at least Emacs 23.2 and the Racket language is not consistent with the requirements for completing SICP exercises...e.g. list mutation. MIT/GNU Scheme is fully compatible with the book.

Comment: Point taken. I recommended `racket` just because I know that `geiser` supports it well. As for the 23.2 concern, well it's 2015 already and even 24.3 is considered outdated.

Comment: The answer is an xyz. Install gieser, install Racket, update Emacs. There are some Linux distros whose standard Emacs package is not compatible with Geiser...so maybe we're onto an xyza' solution.

Comment: I've been in OP's place 2 years ago with exact same problem. I wasn't aware of `geiser` at the time and tried to make SLIME work. Updating Emacs is nothing compared to that.

Comment: So basically, update Emacs, install geiser, and use emacs instead of DrRacket? Is there a tutorial that helps getting this set-up properly and running? When I do "#lang scheme" as the first line in DrRacket, it seems to be running the code properly...

Comment: DrRacket is fine for playing around. But if you're looking to be a power user, you might as well start with Emacs, since DrRacket isn't extend-able. You can update to Emacs24 from the package manager, and install geiser with Emacs's own package manager and that's it. Almost no other config required to get started.